# Load testing application using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, access-token, load-testing, auth0, bearer-token

I am load testing a web application.
I am new to JMeter and have too many confusions.

1. I try to access the website link using JMeter, but the application login is handled by a third party(Auth0) and I am not able to find a way how I can successfully access the application with proper authorization.

Is it possible to give the access token somewhere in the Jmeter, so I can skip the redirecting to Auth0 page for logging in and entering username and password

If so how can I do it

2. Also, even if I access the website pages without username and password, still Jmeter returns a status code 200.

Even if I access the application successfully still the status code will be the same.

How do I differentiate if Jmeter is successfully opening the link I passed or is stuck at the login page to which it is redirected to.

3. Is there a way to interpret the response body, like what page is Jmeter seeing now,

I have been trying to a find a way for so long now, so any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1/ Yes, use [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and set the token here. Or if it's a parameter set it in HTTP Request parameters table

2/ JMeter marks a sampler in error if return code is >=400. So if response code is 200 but page is not expected one, you need to use [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to test presence of a particular content

3/ Yes, in View Results Tree either use in the select box in the middle on the left the renderers HTML with embedded resources or Browser

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Comment: So what I do is, I  create a Thread Group, specify the address in HTTP request, and now I will have to add the HTTP header manager, give the parameter name as accesstoken(?) and value as Bearer<token>.        Is that all...      Am I right    @ubikloadpack

Comment: So I tried the Http Header Manager, created a field Authorization and gave the value as Bearer (token which I got from the developer tools). The response code is 200, but I am not knowing if it is accessing the right pages

Comment: The header is usually named Authorization and looks like this:    Authorization: Bearer <token>. But ideally to avoid making an error why don't you use recording ? Please update your question to show what you did with screenshot. If answer is ok, accept it so that it helps others. Thanks